# bootstrap underline not working when printing

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

The following codes has underline on webpage. But in browser's print, it shows no underline.

printOrder.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>Dispatch Note</title>
  <link  href="/ocadmin-asset/stylesheet/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
  <link  href="/ocadmin-asset/stylesheet/fonts/fontawesome/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="/ocadmin-asset/javascript/jquery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/ocadmin-asset/javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-print-css/css/bootstrap-print.min.css" media="print">

<style>
@media print {
    @page {
      size: A4;
      margin: 0;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="border: thin solid black;padding:0%">
<table class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Delivery Date<span class="text-decoration-underline">2022-01-01</span>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;Day of week：<span class="text-decoration-underline">Wednesday</span>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;Time：<span class="text-decoration-underline">12:30</span>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;Name：<span class="text-decoration-underline">Adam Smith</span>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;Mobile：<span style="text-decoration: underline !important;">0912-345678</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Chrome:

Webpage has underline
[image]

Printing has no underline
[image]
The last one mobile I use style, not bootstrap's class.

Deos it mean that bootstrap cannot be used in print?

Answer (score 0):

text-decoration-skip-ink is a property that controls the behavior of underlining and overlining (but not line-through) when the line passes through part of a character/glyph. This gives you fine-tuned control over how underlines or overlines interact with the characters that extend above the top or hang below the bottom of a line. Check the link for a more detailed`.line-of-text-thats-already-underlined { text-decoration-skip-ink: none; }` description. [enter link description here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-decoration-skip-ink/)
letme know if it will not work.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work, and it's different situation. It lets the space has underline, too. But my problem is no underline at all.